# EventFlow does not show right telemetry types on ApplicationInsight portal. Instead they show as TRACE

Tags: .net, azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights, event-flow

In my sample project, I am using EventFlow to collect my diagnostic data and output to ApplicationInsight. Logging is also done through ApplicationInsight. Diagnostic data showed up on the ApplicationInsight portal, but all telemetry types show as TRACE (even though diagnostic sends with telemetry type REQUEST). But if I directly log with ApplicationInsight (without EventFlow), it will correctly show the right Telemetry Type in ApplicationInsight. Below is my EventFlow config file and sample code I used.

By the way my sample application is ASP.NET Core2 Web API.

eventFlowConfig.json

```html
{

   "inputs": [
           { "type": "ApplicationInsights" }
  ],
  "outputs": [
    // Please update the instrumentationKey.
    {
      "type": "ApplicationInsights",
      "instrumentationKey": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  ],
  "schemaVersion": "2016-08-11"
}
```

Sample Code

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<EventFlowTelemetryProcessor>();
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var telemetryConfiguration = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<TelemetryConfiguration>();
            var eventFlowTelmetryProcessor = (EventFlowTelemetryProcessor)telemetryConfiguration
                                                .TelemetryProcessors
                                                .First(x => x.GetType() == typeof(EventFlowTelemetryProcessor));

            if (eventFlowTelmetryProcessor != null)
            {
                var diagnosticPipeline = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<DiagnosticPipeline>();
                eventFlowTelmetryProcessor.Pipeline = diagnosticPipeline;
            }

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Here I attached a screenshot of ApplicationInsight for more clarity. Here It has some diagnostic data with telemetry type REQUEST but even those are shown as TRACE.

[image: ApplicationInsight screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It happens because **Event Flow *AppInsights Ouput*** uses *TrackTrace* to handle all input events\telemetry, and these events are sent to the *Trace* table on ApplicationInsights.

It also uses the AppInsights Event Type(Request) to set the LogLevel of these events, Like Informational, Trace, Debug.

Because of this unnecessary processing, you lose something on the way to its destination. Why not log direct to appInsights instead of adding this extra overhead to parse to eventFlow and then send to AppInsights?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems like kind of limitation in EventFlow integration with AI. Answer to question about why can't use AI directly is,  In Product environment It is not suppose use Azure cloud environment and everything would be in on premise but in DEV and QA it would plan to use telemetry data on Azure Cloud for DEV/QA team internal reference. In Product telemetry data would be push to some third party integration like ElasticSearch.

Comment: EventFlow is OpenSource, if you need to support these kind of scenarios, I would recommend you get a copy of the code and customize to your own needs. The current implementation must be generic to support all kind of scenarios, In your case, you will likely face something similar with ElasticSearch Outputs. Please take a look here: https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow